# most efficient way to hash map an object to be keyed by a time range?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, time, hash

example object:

```js
{
    "start": "1.06",
    "end": "2.33",
    "content": "something"
},
{
    "start": "2.99",
    "end": "3.54",
    "content": "something else"
}
```

I want to create an efficient hash map where I can input any time and get the content.  For example, I input `2.01` and I get `something` because that occurred in that time range.

Aside from creating a hash of every single number in the ranges, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: most efficient? All depends on how it is being used.

Comment: If it's sorted, probably some sort of implementation of a quick sort, compairing the value to the start and end.

Comment: Can your data have overlapping periods?

Comment: To clarify @trincot, no the time ranges will always be in consecutive increasing order, and not overlapping

Comment: Then a binary search will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are no overlapping periods, and the data is already sorted, you should implement a binary search:

```
function findIndex(data, time) {
    let left = 0;
    let right = data.length-1;
    while (left <= right) {
        const mid = (right + left)>>1;
        if (time > data[mid].end) {
            left = mid + 1;
        } else if (time < data[mid].start) {
            right = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This will return -1 when there is no match, or the index of the match. With that index you can get the matching object, and one of its properties.

The time complexity is *O(logn)*.

Note: you need to define the start/end properties as ***numbers***, not as strings, so you get a numeric comparison result, and not an alphabetical one.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.  This is better than Array filter which will loop through the entire array every time